# Implementing 3D random walk to simulate a diffusion process

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to implementing arrays in c and I'm trying to implement a program that simulates a 3D random walk diffusion process. A particle starts at the origin (0,0,0) and takes n steps, with equal probability of moving in each of the 6 directions (left/right, forward/backward, up/down); the obtaining the distribution of final locations after n steps by simulate m particles and calculate the proportion of particles within a sphere of radius rn from the origin, for varying values of r from 0.05 to 1.

Currently my code is running into one of two errors, either it would return incorrect result alongside the error: double free or corruption (out). Or it wouldn't return anything but the error: malloc(): corrupted top size

I've tried changing my switch cases in one_particle to if else statements, adding validation to calculate_index, and made sure that I've allocated the grid as n*n*n for 3D walk and haven't to figure out how to get rid of the errors.
Here's the current version of my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <assert.h>


   int calculate_index(int x, int y, int z, int n){

      int index = x + n * (y + n * z);

      if(index < 0 || index >= n*n*n){
        return -1; 
      }

      return index;

    }

     //Simulate one particle moving n steps in random directions
    //Use a random number generator to decide which way to go at every step
    //When the particle stops at a final location, use the memory pointed to by grid to 
    //record the number of particles that stop at this final location

   void one_particle(int *grid, int n)
   {
    int x, y, z;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int direct = rand() % 6;

        switch(direct){
            case 0: x++; break;
            case 1: x--; break;
            case 2: y++; break;
            case 3: y--; break;
            case 4: z++; break;
            case 5: z--; break;
        }
    }
    int index = calculate_index(x, y, z, n);
    grid[index]++;


}


//This function returns the fraction of particles that lie within the distance
//r*n from the origin (including particles exactly r*n away)
//The distance used here is Euclidean distance

double density(int *grid, int n, double r)
{
    int count = 0;
    int radius = (int) (r * n);
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    for(x = -radius; x <= radius; x++){
        for(y = -radius; y <= radius; y++){
            for(z = -radius; z <= radius; z++){
                if(x*x + y*y + z*z <= radius*radius){
                    int index = calculate_index(x, y, z, n);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    double total = n * n * n;
    
    return (double) count / total; 
}


void print_result(int *grid, int n)
{
    printf("radius density\n");
    for(int k = 1; k <= 20; k++)
    {
        printf("%.2lf   %lf\n", 0.05*k, density(grid, n, 0.05*k));
    }
}

void diffusion(int n, int m)
{
    int *grid = calloc(n * n * n, sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 1; i<=m; i++) one_particle(grid, n);

    print_result(grid, n);
    
    free(grid);


}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s n m\n", argv[0]);
        return 0; 
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int m = atoi(argv[2]);

    assert(n >= 1 && n <=50);
    assert(m >= 1 && m <= 1000000);
    srand(12345);
    diffusion(n, m);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my old implementation of the if else statement to replace my switch cases in one_participle as well as my old implementation of the calculate_index function:

```
void one_particle(int *grid, int n)
{
    int x, y, z;
    x = 0; 
    y = 0;
    z = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int direct = rand() % 6;

        if(direct == 0){x++;}
        else if(direct == 1){x--;}
        else if(direct == 2){y++;}
        else if(direct == 3){y--;}
        else if(direct == 4){z++;}
        else{z--;}
    }
    int index = coordinates_index(x, y, z, n);
    grid[index]++;


}

int calculate_index(int x, int y, int z, int n){
    return (x % n + n*(y % n + n*(z % n)));
}
```

And here are the 2 results:

```
$ ./diffusion 10 1000000
radius density
0\.05   0.001000
0\.10   0.007000
0\.15   0.007000
0\.20   0.033000
0\.25   0.033000
0\.30   0.123000
0\.35   0.123000
0\.40   0.257000
0\.45   0.257000
0\.50   0.515000
0\.55   0.515000
0\.60   0.925000
0\.65   0.925000
0\.70   1.419000
0\.75   1.419000
0\.80   2.109000
0\.85   2.109000
0\.90   3.071000
0\.95   3.071000
1\.00   4.169000
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)

$ ./diffusion 10 1000000
malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `grid[index]++;` Right off the bat, the value of `index` can be `-1`... I hope there's more interesting stuff as I read through this code.

Comment: Suggestion: Dimension your cubic matrix with an odd number (eg: `11`, then create particles a the centre (eg `(5,5,5)`) and let them wander about. If a particle _bangs into_ a wall (new index < 0 || new index >= 11 in each of the 3 directions), then reverse taking a step back into the volume. As it stands, the "spherical" evalutation loops are 7/8's wasted effort... Ultimately, you'll want to label particles that all exist at the same time, then move them around to bang into one-another and analyse where some subset has arrived after some interval.)

Comment: Also, within the "double density(int *grid, int n, double r)" function, the compiler sent me a warning that the local variable, "index" was not being used.  The statement "int index = calculate_index(x, y, z, n);" might be something accidently copied or also pointing to some other issue.  If it truly is not needed, it probably should be removed.

Comment: OT: I suggest using more descriptive variable names. The program will be much easier to read and understand if you use names like `num_moves`, `num_particles` instead of `n` and `m`

Comment: If you are only interested in the (radial) distribution, instead of a cubic grid, you may consider an array of the distances from the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Fe2O3 in a comment the "double free or corruption" error is most likely (almost certainly) because you access `grid` with a **negative index**. That will for instance happen if the first random move number is 1, i.e. `x` becomes -1 and the resulting access is `grid[-1]`. That's an illegal access as arrays in C may only be index using `0` to `size-1`. When you do that your code is said to have "undefined behavior" which mean "anything may happen" including a program crash.

In general it makes no sense to reason about "undefined behavior". On a specific system one can dig into the details and analyze exactly what happens. In your case the writes to `grid` using negative numbers have most likely overwritten some memory "owned" by the library functions `calloc`/`free` so when you call `free`, it sees some unexpected garbage values and concludes that some "memory corruption" has happened. But this is pure guessing... again: **in general it makes no sense to reason about "undefined behavior", just fix the bugs.**

In your case fixing the "memory corruption" bug could be done by checking the value of `index` before doing the write, e.g. `if (index < 0 || index >= n*n*n) {... error handling ...};`

That leads to the question: What kind of error handling can be done here?

I may be wrong but it seems to me that your idea was to make the grid sufficiently large to hold all possible positions. If that's the case you need more memory. Like `int *grid = calloc((2*n + 1) * (2*n + 1) * (2*n + 1), sizeof(int));`. Further, you need to add an offset so that origin (0, 0, 0) is "moved" to (n, n, n). In other words, the `calculate_index` function must be updated to handle the offset so that negative `x`, `y`, `z` values still produce a valid `index`.

Another thing about your code is the `density` function which looks strange. The calculated `index` is never used and `grid` is never read. Instead you do some calculation based on `count` which has nothing to do with the simulation performed.